# Confirmation on a probability distribution problem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

So, I've come across the following question and would like to know if I've done it correctly:

A discrete random variable $X$ has the following probability function

$$
P(X=x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{4}(2-x) & \quad x =0,1,2 \\
            \frac{1}{4}(x-2) & \quad x = 3
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Given that two observations, $X_1$ and $X_2$, are made on $X$, show that

$a)~P(X_1+X_2=5)=0$

$b)~$Find the complete probability function of $P(X_1+X_2=x)$

For $a)$: My logic was as follows: consider the pairs of $X_1$ and $X_2$ that sum to give $5$ and then consider the probability of each pair as follows $P(X=X_1)P(X=X_2)$ and then, as you do, sum together the probability of each pair to find the total probability. Hence, for the case of $P(X_1+X_2=5)$, we have $X_1:2,3$ and $X_2:3,2$, hence we have $$P(X=2)P(X=3)+P(X=3)P(X=2)=(0)(0.25)+(0.25)(0)=0$$ now for $b)$, we have to consider the range of $X_1+X_2$ as a whole. With the values $0$ to $3$ inclusive, we have a range of $0$ to $6$, and the best way to explain the procedure from here is with a table:
$$
\begin{array}{ c c c }
 X_1+X_2 & X_1 & X_2 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 \\  
 1 & 1,0 & 0,1 \\
 2 & 0,1,2 & 2,1,0 \\
 3 & 0,1,2,3 & 3,2,1,0 \\
 4 & 1,2,3 & 3,2,1 \\
 5 & 3,2 & 2,3 \\
 6 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
$$
if we then consider the probability of each case in the same way we did the $P(X_1+X_2=5)$, we get the following probability distribution:

$$
\begin{array}{c c c c c c c c}
 x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 P(X_1+X_2=x) & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{16} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{8} & 0 & \frac{1}{16}
\end{array}
$$
hence the complete probability function is:
$$
P(X_1+X_2=x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{4} & \quad x =0,1,3 \\
            \frac{1}{8} & \quad x = 4 \\
            \frac{1}{16} & \quad x=2,6 \\
            0 & \quad x=5, otherwise
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
We can do a check to confirm whether it is correct, by considering $\Sigma P(X_1+X_2=x)=1$, so we consider whether or not $\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{8} +\frac{2}{16}=1$, which it does, so we conclude that the distribution and it's corresponding function are correct.

But is it correct? And is there an easier approach? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It looks very right to me. I can´t imagine an easier approach.